# Error reading Excel file with vb .net OleDB

Tags: vb.net, excel, oledb

Good Morning,
use the following code to read an Excel file.

```
[CODE]

    strFClasse = oCld.GetSettingBus("BSJVE001", "OPZIONI", ".", "FileClasse", Path.Combine(oApp.AscDir, "Classi.xls"), " ",   Path.Combine(oApp.AscDir, "Classi.xls"))
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & strFClasse & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    MyConnection.Open()

    strSCl = "SELECT * FROM [Classi$A:B] WHERE [Group] = " & CStrSQL(strCodIn)
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSCl, MyConnection)
    MyCommand.Fill(dtTemp)
[/CODE]
```

In test runs everything (windows 7) in production I get the following error:

> OleDbException: -2147467259 - Error creating file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using it like this OLEDB will attempt to create a file if it can't find it. I suspect that your server can't access the path and so assumes the file doesn't exist and then tries to create it. This also fails so you get the "Error Creating File" error. Check security on the path.

Incidentally you should be using the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider as V4.0 is really old now.

You can also add in HDR=Yes and IMEX=1 to you connection string. The first indicates whether the sheet has column names in the first row and the second tells OLEDB that columns should be treated as text. This helps to avoid all sort of problems with mixed data columns.

Finally it is good practice to explicit define variables.

```
Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for additional causes for this generic error,  I've  seen this error if you add additional unnecessary spaces into the file path. For example, in "c:\Folder1 \Folder2\Myfile.xls" the additional space after "Folder1" seems to generate this sort of error as well.